# ¿Cómo agregar configuraciones a codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

Me gustaria saber como puedo agregar alguna configuración en Codeigniter, es decir agregar el nombre de mi proyecto pero haciéndolo global, algo así como base_url.

Desde ya muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para poder usar configuraciones en codeigniter, tienes que usar la [clase configuración](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/config.html), automaticamente codeigniter carga la configuracion almacenada en el archivo *application/config/config.php* en este puedes colocar tus configuraciones, y si quieres usar otro archivo puedes cargarlo con:

```
$this->config->load('filename')
```

Este archivo tiene que esta en la carpeta *application/config*.

El archivo tiene que tener las configuraciones en formato arreglo, por ejemplo:

```
$config['project_name'] = 'Test';
```

luego para obtener un elemento de la configuración usas:

```
$this->config->item('project_name');
```

Comment: Excelente- funciona de manera correcta. Gracias!

Comment: La información se puede agregar desde base de datos? en caso de que si como se podría hacer?